# Oralce Error : literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
          TB_A.this_week_monday 
        , TB_A.this_week_sunday 
        , TB_B.IMG_LCL_NM 
        , TB_B.IMG_NM 
        , TB_B.IMG_URL 
        , TB_B.EPS_SEQ 
        , TB_C.GR_NM
        , TB_C.GR_CL_CD 
        , TB_C.MBR_NO
        , CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') = 'MON' AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:59:59' 
               THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS GRD_CLT_YN 
        , CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') = 'MON' AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:59:59' 
               THEN CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                 FROM TB_BRND_BNFT
                                WHERE BNFT_STA_DT >= TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-7, 'monday')) AND 
                                      BNFT_END_DT < TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'monday')+1)
                           ) > 0 
                    THEN 'case 1'
                    ELSE 'case 2'
                END 
               ELSE 'case 3'
          END AS CMMT
   FROM ( SELECT 
                 SYSDATE + (1 - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D'))+ 1 AS this_week_monday
               , SYSDATE + (1 - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D'))+ 7 AS this_week_sunday
            FROM DUAL
        )TB_A
      , ( SELECT 
                 IMG_LCL_NM 
               , IMG_NM 
               , IMG_URL 
               , B.EPS_SEQ 
            FROM TB_BRND_MGMT A JOIN TB_BRND_BNFT B ON A.GRP_MCHT_NO = B.GRP_MCHT_NO
           WHERE BNFT_STA_DT >= TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-7, 'monday')) AND 
                 BNFT_END_DT < TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'monday')+1)
        ) TB_B
    , (
       SELECT 
               GR_NM 
         , TB_MBR_GR.GR_CL_CD 
                 , APLY_STA_DT 
         , MBR_NO 
        FROM TB_MBR_GR 
        LEFT JOIN TB_MBR_GR_SET 
                ON TB_MBR_GR.GR_CL_CD = TB_MBR_GR_SET.GR_CL_CD
        WHERE MBR_NO = '2000000001'
        ORDER BY APLY_STA_DT DESC 
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
       ) TB_C
;
```

The error "literal does not match format string" continues to occur.
'BNFT_STA_DT' and 'BNFT_END_DT' are of varchar2 type.
I think there is something wrong with the sysdate and next_day functions.
I don't know where or how to fix it. help!

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: `BNFT_STA_DT >= TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-7, 'monday'))` You are trying to compare a VARCHAR2 with a DATE. Oracle will try to convert one of those values to the type of the other and that is obviously not working. Hence you need to explicitly convert one of the values. Either use TO_CHAR to convert the DATE to VARCHAR2 or use TO_DATE to convert the VARCHAR2 to  DATE.

Comment: If BNFT_STA_DT and BNFT_END_DT are varchar2, then convert them to date using to_date with the appropriate format mask. And why are they varchar2? This looks like being a database design issue: wherever you have to store a calendar date use a date data type column. Otherwise, how can you be sure you will not get to store garbage in the database. Also, when converting to date, if you have Oracle version >12, use default null on conversion error.

Comment: Be aware, result of `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D'))` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY`, thus I would not see it as an reliable approach. Maybe better use `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')` which is always Monday of current week (according to ISO-8601).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_DATE` to convert strings to dates (and should not store dates in `VARCHAR2` fields) and can use `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')` to find midnight Monday of the current week.

If, for example, your date data is stored in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` then:

```sql
SELECT TB_A.this_week_monday 
     , TB_A.this_week_sunday 
     , TB_B.IMG_LCL_NM 
     , TB_B.IMG_NM 
     , TB_B.IMG_URL 
     , TB_B.EPS_SEQ 
     , TB_C.GR_NM
     , TB_C.GR_CL_CD 
     , TB_C.MBR_NO
     , CASE
       WHEN SYSDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '9' HOUR
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS GRD_CLT_YN 
     , CASE
       WHEN SYSDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '9' HOUR
       THEN CASE
            WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM   TB_BRND_BNFT
                   WHERE  TO_DATE(BNFT_STA_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                   AND    TO_DATE(BNFT_END_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 8 ) > 0 
            THEN 'case 1'
            ELSE 'case 2'
            END 
       ELSE 'case 3'
       END AS CMMT
FROM   ( SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') AS this_week_monday
              , TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 6 AS this_week_sunday
         FROM   DUAL
       ) TB_A
     , ( SELECT IMG_LCL_NM 
              , IMG_NM 
              , IMG_URL 
              , B.EPS_SEQ 
         FROM   TB_BRND_MGMT A
                JOIN TB_BRND_BNFT B
                ON A.GRP_MCHT_NO = B.GRP_MCHT_NO
         WHERE  TO_DATE(BNFT_STA_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
         AND    TO_DATE(BNFT_END_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 8
       ) TB_B
     , ( SELECT GR_NM 
              , TB_MBR_GR.GR_CL_CD 
              , APLY_STA_DT 
              , MBR_NO 
         FROM   TB_MBR_GR 
                LEFT JOIN TB_MBR_GR_SET 
                ON TB_MBR_GR.GR_CL_CD = TB_MBR_GR_SET.GR_CL_CD
         WHERE  MBR_NO = '2000000001'
         ORDER BY APLY_STA_DT DESC 
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
       ) TB_C
;
```